# Does using setpriority() have any affect if my scheduling policy is SCHED_OTHER

Tags: c, linux, nice

My scheduling policy is SCHED_OTHER. Will the change in in nice value using setpriority() have any affect.
When I used it, I dint see any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The answer is no. The setpriority should not affect the process in this case. As per the documentation:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/setpriority

> Any processes or threads using SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR shall be unaffected by a call to setpriority(). This is not considered an error. A process which subsequently reverts to SCHED_OTHER need not have its priority affected by such a setpriority() call.</del>

I'm sorry but reading carefuly the http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html:

> SCHED_OTHER: Default Linux time-sharing scheduling
>          SCHED_OTHER can be used at only static priority 0.  SCHED_OTHER is
>          the standard Linux time-sharing scheduler that is intended for all
>          threads that do not require the special real-time mechanisms.  The
>          thread to run is chosen from the static priority 0 list based on a
>          dynamic priority that is determined only inside this list.  The
>          dynamic priority is based on the nice value (set by nice(2),
>          setpriority(2), or sched_setattr(2)) and increased for each time
>          quantum the thread is ready to run, but denied to run by the
>          scheduler.  This ensures fair progress among all SCHED_OTHER threads.

Thus, the **dynamic** priority of the threads is affected by the call to setpriority and it should cause changes in the scheduling (depending on the new priority value being set in the call).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, is there any way if can stop a process from occupying the total CPU at given point of time.                                                                     Please note that i cannot change to ant other scheduling method.

Comment: In order to make a process occupy less CPU you have to increase its nice (higher nice values -> low priority) value through by using nice or setpriority.

Comment: I have done it using setpriority(19), but it is not affecting  the process CPU usage. At one point my process goes through recursive function calls, and CPU usage goes to 95%. So I have increased the nice value before my recursive function is called. But, this doesnot seem to work.

Comment: Do you other processes running at the same time with the same priority and which doesn't get CPU?

Answer (score 0):

You can also lower dynamic priority by using nice().

Try nice(9).

```
    #include <unistd.h>
    int nice(int inc);  // inc = increase, added to the current nice value
```